# Duda sobre cómo definir una plantilla diferente para cada post según la categoría

Tags: php, wordpress

les comento mi situación. Actualmente tengo 45 `plantillas de páginas` que uso para mostrar 45 tipos de `ítems`, cada una de esas páginas consta de una tabla común a las 45 plantillas, y la única razón por la cual he creado esas 45 plantillas de páginas es porque `en cada página muestro las publicaciones de determinadas categorías`, es decir, cada página representa a una categoría principal.

**Las 45 plantillas de página:**

[image: Las 45 plantillas de página]

**La tabla que muestro en las 45 páginas:**
[image: La tabla]

Entonces, mi dolor de cabeza es de esperarse cada vez que quiero añadir alguna nueva funcionalidad o cambiar algún aspecto de diseño y tener que hacerlo con 45 páginas y que todo quede idéntico... novatadas que debo pagar.

Por lo tanto me he puesto a investigar y encontré la manera de `definir` una `plantilla de página` diferente `según` `la categoría`:

```
// Filtrando por slug
if (in_category('noticias')) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-noticias.php');
} elseif (in_category('eventos')) {
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-eventos.php');
} else { // Sino, cargo otro single por defecto
    include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');
}
```

`Eso me da la posibilidad de establecer una única plantilla` para cargar / mostrar las publicaciones de esa(s) categoría(s) en particular, y ya no tendría que editar 45 páginas, sino 1 página...que maravilla.

Ahora bien... mi idea al principio fue la de crear `45 páginas` para mostrar cosas de `45 categorías`, para ello tengo este loop:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'category_name' => $cat_name_a, 'posts_per_page' => 700 ) ); 
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
     ...
     ...
     ...
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Donde `$post_type` y `$category_name` los edito a mano uno por uno en cada página, y antes del loop:

```
$post_type = 'item';
$cat_name_a = 'armaduras';
```

Y lo demás son 45 historias...

Con todo lo anterior, mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo seguir cargando el contenido según la `categoría`? ¿Que `category_name` voy a colocar en el `loop` para `mostrar 45 categorías` - `ojo, una por cada página` - no todas al mismo tiempo, para que no cambie el comportamiento actual? En este momento todo funciona perfecto, entras a la página de cascos y te muestra todos los cascos, entras a la de armaduras y muestra todas las armaduras, y así, todo según la categoría que define a esa publicación...

[Aquí está la muestra][3], baja un poquito y en **Equipos para el Cuerpo**, `las primeras 6 páginas`. Ellas muestran una o varias publicaciones en una `tabla` (`la que mencioné al principio`), esas publicaciones `están asignadas a una categoría con el mismo nombre de la página`, es decir, `cascos, armaduras, escudos, pantalones, botas`, etc... por lo tanto cada publicación se muestra donde tiene que ir.

En cada página editaba manualmente la variable `$cat_name_a = 'armaduras';` que define el `category_name` para las publicaciones que muestra el `loop`, pero con la asignación de plantillas según la categoría no se como seguir mostrando esas publicaciones como lo vengo haciendo.

*Si alguien me puede ayudar le estaré muy agradecido. Y de antemano muchas gracias por pasar a leerme.*

**Otros datos:**

- No se si afecta que las `publicaciones` que quiero mostrar tienen más
  de una categoría asignada, dentro de ellas una `categoría` que es
  principal y es la que uso para mostrar ese contenido asignado a ella.
- Esas publicaciones provienen de un `custom_post`.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! No me ha quedado muy claro como se organiza con las plantillas, así que incluyo un código para las páginas de posts (`single-$posttype.php` o `single.php`). En [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) puede encontrar la información para elegir en que archivos incluir el código.

Para `single-$posttype.php` o `single.php`:

```
<?php defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'Wrong Access' );
global $post; // Contiene el post solicitado

// A continuación se obtienen todas las categorías a las que pertenece el post solicitado
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy_name' ); // taxonomy_name no es cascos, ni armaduaras, ni el nombre de ningún elemento de la categoría, si no el slug de la categoría. Por ejemplo, 'category' para las categorías de los posts de Wordpress
// No se como marcas una categoría como principal, así que se utilizará la primera como si fuera la principal
$main_cat = !is_wp_error( $terms ) ? current( $terms ) : null; // $terms sólo será un WP_Error si has utilizado un 'taxonomy_name' inexistente
$cat_template = $main_cat ? locate_template( 'single-' . $main_cat->slug . '.php' ) : null; // localiza la plantilla para cada categoría
// NOTA: Yo no utilizaría el prefijo single- para las plantillas, ya que está reservado para plantillas de posts 

get_header(); ?>
<?php if( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
 <?php if( $cat_template ) include( $cat_template ); // al insertar la plantilla mediante include, ésta dispondrá de las variables definidas en este script. También puede utilizarse get_template_part(), pero solo se le pueden pasar variables desde Wordpress 5.5.0 ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```